# Show embedded picture using node (nodemailer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, outlook, nodemailer

I use nodemailer to send mail with a embedded picture,

```
var mailOption = {
    html: 'Embedded image: <img src="cid:unique@kreata.ee"/>',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'image.jpg',
        content: '/9j/4AA ... Q==',
        encoding: 'base64',
        cid: 'unique@kreata.ee'
    }]
    from: '...',
    to: '...',
    subject: '...'
}
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();
transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, info) {
    ...
});
```

I can recieved the mail from Outlook, However the picture cannot show in Outlook. I have 2 question,

1. How to show picture in Outlook using nodemailer module (or others)
2. How can I print the entire mail include header and body in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the message in Outlook and check if the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property is really set to `"unique@kreata.ee"`  and the HTML body (`PR_HTML` property) references the image using the specified `cid`. You can see the data in Outlook using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): select the message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy toolbar. To see the attachment properties, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab and double click on the attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I installed OutlookSpy and could not find PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property. and nothing displayed In GetAttachmentTable tab. Do you know how can i check on the server side to find the reason?

Comment: If nothing is present in the GetAttachmentTable tab, that means there are no attachments. What do you see in the HTML body?

Answer (score 1):

I find the reason of Problem.
the module 'nodemailer' I download and installed is the version 0.6.x
which have some issue of attachments. ( I haven't check the reason)

After reinstall the version 1.2.x, the attachment works fine.